# Is there an equivalent to pixel based flex-basis in Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material

I have an app that uses angular material and I would like 1 child to have a fix width. I can't seem to get this to work unless I do something like this...

```
div(style="flex-basis:100px")
```

Which is not acceptable. Is there a way to do this using the ngMaterial lib or do I have to use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, angular material does not have an option for flex-basis yet (as of v1.1.0-RC5).

What you've got is probably the best solution unfortunately.